# We're sorry. We can't open the workbook in the browser because it uses these unsupported features: • Interactive report sheets

Tags: 2013, excel, powerpivot

I use `SharePoint 2013` and `Power Pivot Services`.

I create a Excel report with Power Pivot and I fetch data from my `Data Warehouse`.

I upload this `Excel file` in SharePoint Documents.

For update my `Data Set` from my Data Warehouse, I create a schedule over this file.

[image]

And in this page, I configure a schedule for update automatically from `Data Warehouse`  .

[image]

[image]

But I get this error :

[image]

```
We're sorry. 
We can't open the workbook in the browser 
because it uses these unsupported features: • Interactive report sheets
```

And when I want configure like this configuration :

[image]

But I get this error again:

[image]

```
We're sorry. 
We can't open the workbook in the browser 
because it uses these unsupported features: • Interactive report sheets
```

this is my SSS :

[image]

And when I want configure like this configuration :

[image]

I get this error again :

[image]

```
We're sorry. 
We can't open the workbook in the browser 
because it uses these unsupported features: • Interactive report sheets
```

This is my SSS Configuration :

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I configure Auto refresh in `Power Pivot Report` in `Share Point 2013` when I use Oracle Connection in my excel report?

For more description I configure my SSAS in Share Point Mode.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately this limitation is being in SharePoint 2013 
for create the connection to power pivot data model follow this blow links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230901.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213103.aspx#bkmk_create

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230813.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Scheduled Data Refresh is not supported for Workbooks that contain Power View content. You can create a schedule for the refresh of the workbook, however the workbook will not be refreshed and you will see an error message similar to the following in the “Data Refresh History page”:

“We're sorry. We can't open the workbook in the browser because it uses these unsupported features:    • Interactive report sheets”

**Applies To:**
Microsoft SharePoint 2013 and SQL Server Analysis Services 2012 SP1 server running in SharePoint Mode.

**Work around**
To work around this limitation, you can use a two workbook approach, separating the data model from the Power View sheets. Refresh can be configured for the workbook that contains the data model.

1. Create a PowerPivot workbook that contains the data model
2. Schedule a data refresh on the data model workbook.
3. Create a second workbook that contains your Excel sheets and Power
   View sheets. This second workbook uses the first workbook as a datasource.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14060.powerpivot-data-refresh-error-with-interactive-report-sheets-power-view.aspx

Comment: I do all this notes. but it not work.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: I do all this note but I get yet this error : “We're sorry. We can't open the workbook in the browser because it uses these unsupported features: • Interactive report sheets”

Comment: I Edit my question and add my SSAS Configuration.